# How to figure out what methods are available?

Tags: rust

I have created a `SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>` via

```rust
let (write, read) = ws_stream.split();
```

How can I see which methods are available for `write`? The documentation for `SplitSink` doesn't actually list any methods: it just lists a long list of traits, and I have to click on each and every one of them?

How can I simply find out how to write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [this `SplitSink`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.SplitSink.html), I see three "interesting" traits on that page. There's `Debug`, `Sink`, and `Unpin`.

The "Auto Trait Implementations" section is for things like `Send` and `Sync` that the compiler implements for you, and "Blanket Implementations" are (usually trivial) implementations defined for all types of a particular class. For instance, one of the blanket implementations listed is `impl From<SplitSink> for SplitSink` (generic arguments omitted for simplicity) which says "If I have a `SplitSink`, I can convert it into a `SplitSink`". This doesn't say anything specific about a `SplitSink`, it's just a property a lot of types (in this case, all types) have in Rust, and `SplitSink` happens to be an example.

So only three are written specifically *for* this type. Of those, `Debug` is for debugging, naturally, and involves printing the object's innards to the screen. `Unpin` is a more complicated move-semantics trick you can read about [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/marker/trait.Unpin.html), but it's a borrow semantics thing, not a capability of the type itself in terms of the public API you're probably looking for. So that just leaves [`Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html), which looks like it has several ways to send data to a `Sink`.

Comment: One of those blanket implementations is `SinkExt` which is probably the most important source of methods to mention.

Comment: That's what I thought, but `SinkExt` claims to provide a method send, and `write.send(...)` gives `write.send("a"); - method not found in SplitSink<WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::MaybeTlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>>, Message>`

Comment: @kmdreko Oof, I'm so used to ignoring blanket impls that I didn't see the extension trait down there. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Test are you sure you brought the trait into scope?

Comment: @kmdreko that was exactly it, thank you. I'm sorry, I'm still learning to not make errors like these and figure it out for myself. It's hard to tell when it's something simple and when it's complicated and worth asking about.

Comment: And now of course everything compiles but the websocket client isn't sending messages...why is it so painful to take everything I"ve been working on and make a beautiful miminal example to ask about it...this will never get done